# Hibernate 6 SQLFunctionTemplate Alternative

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

We have HibernateMetadataBuilderContributor Like below. Which works in Hibernate 5 or Spring boot 2.7. But not working when we migrate to Hibernate 6 or Spring boot 3.

```
public class HibernateMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    public static final String STRING_AGG = "string_agg";
    public static final String STRING_AGG_ORDER_BY = "string_agg_order_by";
    public static final String STRING_AGG_DISTINCT = "string_agg_distinct";

    @Override
    public void contribute(final MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(STRING_AGG, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)"));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(STRING_AGG_ORDER_BY, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2 order by ?3)"));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(STRING_AGG_DISTINCT, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(distinct ?1, ?2)"));

    }
}
```

SQLFunctionTemplate is not found in Hibernate 6, what is the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

### Hibernate 5

In Hibernate 5, this is how we used to register an SQL function with multiple parameters:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
 
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "date_trunc",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,
                "date_trunc('day', (?1 AT TIME ZONE ?2))"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

### Hibernate 6

In Hibernate 6, the same function can be registered like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
 
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "date_trunc",
            DateTruncFunction.INSTANCE
        );
    }
 
    public static class DateTruncFunction extends NamedSqmFunctionDescriptor {
         
        public static final DateTruncFunction INSTANCE = new DateTruncFunction();
 
        public DateTruncFunction() {
            super(
                "date_trunc",
                false,
                StandardArgumentsValidators.exactly(2),
                null
            );
        }
 
        public void render(
                SqlAppender sqlAppender,
                List<? extends SqlAstNode> arguments,
                SqlAstTranslator<?> walker) {
            Expression timestamp = (Expression) arguments.get(0);
            Expression timezone = (Expression) arguments.get(1);
            sqlAppender.appendSql("date_trunc('day', (");
            walker.render(timestamp, SqlAstNodeRenderingMode.DEFAULT);
            sqlAppender.appendSql(" AT TIME ZONE ");
            walker.render(timezone, SqlAstNodeRenderingMode.DEFAULT);
            sqlAppender.appendSql("))");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But still there will be a depreciation warning! Do we have any other alternative to use {@link TypeContributor}, {@link FunctionContributor} or
 * {@link AdditionalMappingContributor} instead depending on need

Comment: Any alternative solution as it is depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using in the below way seems working.

```
new PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor(
                new PatternRenderer(pattern),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                name,
                FunctionKind.NORMAL,
                null
        );
```

Comment: Yeah I guess that would probebly work, but you won't get any nice typechecking or anything. If you fill in those null arguments with something sensible, HQL will do a much better job with the typing.

Comment: Seems except these, others arguments in PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor are interfaces, I have to implement, which I am not sure, what to use.

Comment: Well, like I commented below, you can find implementations in `StandardArgumentsValidators`, `StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers`, and `StandardFunctionArgumentTypeResolvers`. (They're very trivial.)

Comment: @GavinKing what is the final argument (argumentListSignature) supposed to be? e.g. for a binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

First: you don't need to do this in H6!

HQL now comes with a built-in `listagg()` function which is automatically translated to `string_agg()` on those databases where that's what it's called. Please check the User Guide chapter on HQL for a full list of built-in portable functions.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions-orderedset

Now, with that said...

The equivalent interface to `SQLFunction` in H6 is `SqmFunctionDescriptor`, which has lots of built-in implementations you could look at for inspiration, including `PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor`.

But the basic, simplified, "user-friendly" implementation we provide is still `org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction`, which has now been adapted to the new, much more-powerful `SqmFunctionDescriptor` framwork.

Comment: We have Postgres's array_agg function also, is there any hibernate 6 function for this. And any examples how to implement PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor

Comment: Ah, right, `array_agg` is already on the todo list: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/5562

Comment: I don't think you need to *implement* `PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor` ... I think you can just instantiate it, can't you?

Comment: You might appreciate the help of `StandardArgumentsValidators`, `StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers`, and `StandardFunctionArgumentTypeResolvers`, but it's basically just a matter of `new`ing it.

Comment: @GavinKing I found this thread here and I am just wondering if hibernate 6 has something built in to replace a custom CastInterval function that I created by overwriting the render function of SQLFunctions like so:

      override fun render(
        firstArgumentType: Type?,
        args: List<*>,
        factory: SessionFactoryImplementor?
      ): String {
        return "cast(" + args[0] + " as interval)"
      }

Comment: Good question. So *currently* in HQL6, you can cast *from* a `Duration` to a numeric type, but because of the intricacies of mapping `Duration` to SQL, there is no built-in way to typecast something *to* a `Duration`. But it is on my radar as a thing we would like to have. If it's very important to you, opening an issue might help.